# inconsistent behavior while accessing session variables in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

My web server - tomcat sets two attributes in the session. In the jsp page, am retrieving them as

```
<% String age = (String) session.getAttribute("age"); %>
```

Am setting this value to a hidden field in the form in the same jsp file.

```
<input type="hidden" name="age" id="age" value="<%=age%>" />
```

And am trying to use this value in javascript file as below

```
document.cForm.age.value
```

But this value is null for most of the times. Sometimes, the variable to set to proper value? Is there any reason for this inconsistency? Please explain

Comment: View the generated source and see what has been output for <%=age%>, that should give you some idea.

Comment: Hi Kris, i viewed source, actually i have two hidden fields in my form, but only one is displayed in the 'view source'. the 'age' field is missing. very weird. 
<code>
<input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="<%=url%>" />
<input type="hidden" name="age" id="age" value="<%=age%>" />
</code>
Any syntax issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try to get the value on DOM load not inline. i mean inside a $(document).ready(function() {})

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Are you saying 
<% String age = (String) session.getAttribute("age"); %>

should come in the function you said.

Comment: Hi Amar, Is there a way to do this without jquery? Am not familiar with jquery

Comment: window.onload = function() {alert(document.cForm.age.value) } inside script tags at the end of the page

Comment: you should also consider what Kris has said. May be the session variable itself may be null.

Comment: You can also try out document.getElementById('age').getAttribute('value')

Comment: I dont know why it was down voted? accessing document before loading will throw error in IE. No explanation on why it was down voted as well.